# How to do Data Augmentation efficiently in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, data-augmentation

First of all I'm asking that because of this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).

When I heard about Data Augmentation the definition I learned was something like: "It's a technique where we create more data to our dataset transforming some samples of our current dataset (transformations like rotations, flips, brightness etc).".

But in that tutorial they're just overwriting the current dataset with transformed samples not adding new data ... Or I'm wrong ?

The correct way of doing that wouldn't be get N random samples, transform them and add them to the dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most frameworks, random augmentation includes no augmentation (random flipping may either flip or not, random rotation angle can be 0 or nigh). This is also randomized every epoch (or whenever your dataset entry is otherwise sampled). Thus the model should eventually see the original image and lots of its possible augmentations.

Comment: Yes, makes sense! Even if they aren't creating new transformed random data samples and save them, the network in each epoch is "seeing" new data so it's Data Augmentation. 
Never thought in that way, thanks!